# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\pear\PEAR')

Tags: php, symfony, pear, symfony-2.2, adsapi-php.ini

I am new to Symfony for a project. I am getting the following error when everything is okay.
[My Symfony](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YPrs.png)

**My php.ini file**

```
[PHP]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About php.ini   ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
;Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\pear\PEAR"
;PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;C:\xampp\php\pear\PEAR"
; http://php.net/include-path
```

Tried every solution available but can't able to solve the problem. Wasted 3 days already. Can anyone help me out?
Many thanks.

Comment: Also, I am using Symfony2

Comment: `app/bootstrap.php.cache` is generated as part of the installation process.  Seems to be missing in your case.  Instead of claiming to have `tried every solution available` it might be more useful to list the steps you took to install the application.

Comment: it was missing from installation packages as well. So added it manually as instructed by the command written below.

Comment: To be clear, the cache file is generated as part of the installation process.  It is not delivered.  Important distinction.  The fact that build_bootstrap was never run implies other issues with the installation process which means you will probably encounter other problems.  Not surprising since Symfony 2 is ancient.  In any event if the answer helped then consider upvoting/accepting it.  If nothing else it might help when asking future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to execute this command

```
sudo php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

Comment: Also, accept my questions, as my reputation is low.
thanks.